# ListView with rounded corners

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to round the corners of the ListView. I have tried to use the `Template` property, but it seems that I would have to rewrite the entire template. Is there any way to get to the border so that I can set the `CornerRadius`

Comment: Only a comment.  Did you try style?

Comment: @Blam Kind of, in that I thought about it, but could not figure out how I could use it in this case

Comment: This might also help: 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757296/wpf-rounded-border-listview-clipping-issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ignore the BorderThickness and CornerRadius values , you can set them according to your requirement.

```
 <ListView>
        <ListView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="50" BorderBrush="Red">
                    <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>
        <ListViewItem Content="Harish"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Harish"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Harish"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Harish"/>
    </ListView>
```

I hope this will help