# WPF Rounded Border ListView clipping Issue

Tags: wpf, listview, border, rounded-corners, clip

I have a `ListView` with a rounded border.

When you click on a `ListVIewItem`, an arrow that sticks out of the `ListView` (by changing the margin) appears.

It looks good at first, but once you click an item, the first and last items stick out of the `ListView`'s rounded border.

Why is this happening and how do I resolve it?

[image: Unselected]

[image: Selected]

Relevant Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFJonnyStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowedItemsControl" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">                
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF9DD3ED" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15"  >
                <Grid>
                <Border Name="mask" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15"  />
                    <ItemsPresenter>
                        <ItemsPresenter.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}" />
                        </ItemsPresenter.OpacityMask>
                    </ItemsPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </Border>  
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowedItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="#FF9DD3ED" CornerRadius="15">

                <Grid Background="White" Height="40">

                    <ed:BlockArrow Margin="-22 0 0 0"  x:Name="fancyArrow" Fill="#FF0C8CCB" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                       FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ArrowBodySize="1" 
                                       Height="40" StrokeThickness="2" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>

                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="ed:BlockArrow.Visibility" TargetName="fancyArrow" Value="Visible"/>                        
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular"/>                        
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ArrowedItem}"/>
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FFEFEFF2">
    <ListView Width="100" Height="250" Template="{DynamicResource ArrowedItemsControl}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ListViewItem >Car</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >Tractor</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >Train</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >Plane</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >Rocket</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >Helicopter</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hove you thought about how it should look when the first item is selected, i would highly recommend not to use such type of menu.

Comment: It looks great, and it's a requirement we have to fulfill, so we don't really have an option here.

Comment: If anyone is having trouble recreating this in XamlPad or Kaxaml, replace the arrow with rectangle - it would have the same effect.

Comment: One more thing.. the rounded border solution is taken from [here](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/wpf-easy-rounded-corners-for-anything/) and might have something to do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfqr44bj3dtxsy3/ArrowedListView.rar)

Main Issue was the `ListViewItem`'s White `Background` getting applied over the `ListView`'s `Border` while rendering. Hence setting that to `Transparent` addresses the main issue but it also needed a few other fixes because of this change such as the separator `Border` clipping between the `ListViewItem`'s

Everything related to this issue in the attached download project is in "MainWindow.xaml"

Comment: Thanks Viv! Simpler than I though :)